# Qbittorrent Api error: AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'download_from_link'

Tags: python, torrent

I'm trying to use the qbittorrent api to download links from magnet links, and I don't seem to remember running into this error before. Feels like it's a recent thing, because this section of my code worked fine before. Here is an example of the code

quick note! I know the link comes from the piratebay, but I was just grabbing a magnet link, it links to wallpapers which are not copyrighted, there is no piracy happening, I just needed a link for an example:

```
self.qbtNoxThread = threading.Thread(target = self.__startQbittorrentNox, daemon = True)
self.qbtNoxThread.start()
qbt_client = qbittorrentapi.Client(host='localhost', port=8080, username='admin', password='adminadmin')
        
for i in range(5):
    try:
         qbt_client.auth_log_in()
         self.client = qbt_client
         qbt_client.download_from_link("magnet:?xt=urn:btih:53445B43ADC992F5354EA0BC34A6429187C6459C&dn=100+Beautiful+Ultra+HD+4K+Wallpapers+Pack-78&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.dler.org%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopentracker.i2p.rocks%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2F47.ip-51-68-199.eu%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.internetwarriors.net%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2F9.rarbg.to%3A2920%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.pirateparty.gr%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.cyberia.is%3A6969%2Fannounce")
         print("Qbittorrent login succesful")
         break
    except qbittorrentapi.LoginFailed as e:
         print(e)
         time.sleep(1) #sometimes the qbtnox server needs a second to boot up or something.
```

And the error it gives me is: `AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'download_from_link'`

has something changed with the qbittorrent api, or there something I haven't noticed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe you want qbt_client.torrents_add(urls="magnet:?...") https://qbittorrent-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apidoc/torrents.html?highlight=magnet

Comment: That worked! Sorry, I'm new here.. How do I accept your answer?